# Java - double buffering NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d

I'm writing a simple game. I have 3 classes the first one: ball which take care of every thing refereed to it, the second one game which made out of an array of "ball"s and the final one is windows, the one which contains the MAIN thread.

window.paint calls game.draw in order to receive the graphics of the game scene.While the game itself double buffering it in order that the Image object can be moved to the Player's ball location(yet to be implemented).

So my problem caused because I'm creating an Image object but somewhy this initialized to null, thus I get NullPointerException.

Here is the source of the methods which handle the painting:

```
public class MyWindow extends JFrame {
        //...the other code
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            thegame.draw();
            repaint();
        }
}

public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    ball[] cellmap;

    //...the other code

    public void draw(){
        Image GameImage = createImage(800,800);
        Graphics GameGraphics = GameImage.getGraphics();

        for(int i = 0;i<cellmap.length;i++)
            cellmap[i].draw(GameGraphics);

        g.drawImage(GameImage, 0, 0, this); 
    }
}

public class Ball extends JFrame {
        //...the other code
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval((int)(this.x+this.radious),(int)(this.y+this.radious),
                       (int)this.radious,(int)this.radious);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell me you're not actually using lowerCamelCase for classes and UpperCamelCase for variables.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541845/problems-with-createimageint-width-int-height

Comment: This code started to go wrong as soon as the 2nd `JFrame` was introduced, let alone the 3rd one!  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) please read [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=58)

2) not good idea paint directly to the `JFrame`, put your painting to the `JComponent`, `JLabel`, `JPanel`

3) for [Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) in [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) use method `paintComponent`, please not methods `paint(Graphics g)` or `draw(Graphics g)`

4) if you want to delay or animate you painting use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: well I didn't know there is such a naming conventions, so now I fixed it. I've tried to use paintComponent rather then paint, but I could not figure out how to implement it, when I have an array of balls and I have to paint them all.moreover, balls can be created during the game.